# Rename image filename using 'media_handle_upload'

Tags: post-meta, uploads

I need to rename images uploaded by the user when they post on my site.

I have a code that works perfectly to save the image and make it part of the post. But I want the images to be renamed to have the title of the post in their filename.

The code I have:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
$img_id01 = media_handle_upload( 'img_main', $postID );
update_post_meta($postID, 'img_id01', $img_id01);
```

Comment: 'update_post_meta' adds the image to the post 'img_id01' field.
That post is being created by the user in the front-end.
The images are inserted via upload field and I use the 'media_handle_upload' to handle the file upload POST request, and to create the attachment post in the database. But if I don't use the 'update_post_meta' the image don't get inserted in the post.

Comment: I want to rename the image before its saved on the server. Don't want to 'edit' it after the post is created and the images are attached.

Comment: Looking at the [function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7.2/src/wp-admin/includes/file.php#L246) that handles the upload, I can see a call to the function `wp_unique_filename()`, which in itself has a filter `wp_unique_filename` applied before returning the value.

Comment: Ok, I see it. But I have no idea how to use that with the code I have. Any hints?

Comment: You need to make sure that images only get renamed in that specific use case, and not while you upload stuff ie. in the Media Library. But I don't know your code, so it's hard for me to tell.

Comment: We wrote something similar once [here](https://github.com/netzstrategen/wordpress-publishing-importer/blob/master/src/Parser/Post.php#L340-L420) to remove special characters from filenames as Safari were not able to display them. Maybe this helps you.

Comment: The part of the code I posted is the only thing I do with the uploads and it's after I create the post and insert the info into it. That is the last part.

Comment: I'll check the link Fabian, thnx

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test this because I don't have your code, but maybe you can get some ideas from it:

```
add_filter( 'wp_unique_filename', 'custom_image_name', 10, 2 );
$img_id01 = media_handle_upload( 'img_main', $postID );
remove_filter( 'wp_unique_filename', 'custom_image_name', 10, 2 );

function custom_image_name( $filename, $ext ) {

    global $postID;
    $post = get_post( $postID );
    return $filename . '-' . $post->post_name . $ext;
}
```

This is not very elegant because `$postID` needs to be in a global scope, but it might do the job.

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow and see what I get. I'll let you know if it works. Thnx